# How to make HTML5 email validation regex work in C++?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I am trying to validate email both on the client-side and on the server-side. The client-side is JavaScript(web front-end). The server-side is written in C++11.

The regex I am using to validate email is provided by the HTML standard (here)[https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#e-mail-state-(type=email)]. I am reproducing it here for quick reference:

```js
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
```

The validation works on the client-side using JavaScript. But the server-side validation using `std::regex_match` fails.

Following is the C++ code to check valid email:

```cpp
bool is_valid_email(std::string email)
{
    // Regex from HTML5 spec.
    static std::regex const email_regex {R"(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/)"};

    return std::regex_match(email, email_regex);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the first and last `/`. Also,  `regex_match` requires a full string match, you need no `^` at the start and `$` at the end.

Comment: try to validate online with sites like: https://regex101.com/

Comment: could use RFC5322_International versions. if on yiuor browser these shuld match same emails. if not you will have unicode problem. i'm sure html5 is not bias toword basic latin. yes ? these `RFC5322_International` where https://regex101.com/r/slgtgu/1 shuld == https://regex101.com/r/slgtgu/1 Consider using `\p{alnum}` or `[\p{L}\p{N}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/` at both ends of the JavaScript regex literal are *regex delimiter* characters, they are not part of a regular expression pattern.

In C++, you set the regex using either regular or raw *string literals*, do you do not need to include regex delimiters into the pattern.

So, if you have `const regex = /abc/` in JavaScript, you may use

```
std::regex const regex {R"(abc)"};
```

In your case, you do not even need the `^` at the start and `$` at the end of the pattern since `regex_match` requires a full string match:

```
bool is_valid_email(std::string email)
{
    // Regex from HTML5 spec.
    static std::regex const email_regex {R"([a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*)"};
    return std::regex_match(email, email_regex);
}
```

Also, `/` is not a special regex metacharacter, you do not need to escape it.

**NOTE** Since the latest JavaScript ECMAScript implementations support many more regex feature, like infinite-width lookbehind, named capturing groups, it is not always so straight-forward to convert a JavaScript regex pattern to a C++ compatible regex pattern.

Comment: It is a special character *if* you delimit the regular expression with `/`, as is tradition, but as this is not the case here, then it isn't.

Comment: @tadman You may call it a special character, but it is not a regex *pattern special metacharacter*. It has no special meaning in the *regex pattern*. In a regex literal notation, it does.

Comment: Yeah, that's the only reason I mention it. In the original it did.

Answer (score -1):

The regex you are running is expecting a `/` before the start (`^`) and after the end (`$`) of the string.  You need to remove the `/^` and `$/` at the beginning and end:

```
"([a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*)"
```

Comment: The parentheses in `R"(...)"` are part of a raw string literal. OP can't remove them. Your string literal won't work and will throw an exception in C++ code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry about that, corrected my answer.

Comment: It still results in a wrong string pattern, see [this C++ demo](https://ideone.com/U4dfDN) yielding ``([a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*)``.